# How were Sakura's release sequences made?

Tags: anime-production, cardcaptor-sakura

In Cardcaptor Sakura, there's something akin to a transformation sequence where Sakura calls upon the power of the key, and it turns into the staff and she twirls it like a baton. Here's a piece of it:

[image: A part of the "release" scene]

You can see the full sequence I'm talking about in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yuI1IVKrVdQ). It also goes on to show the same sequence in many languages.

Normally I'd expect transformations like that to be made once and just reused as necessary since (AFAIK) magical girls usually transform into the same outfits. But in Sakura's case, she stays in whatever she's already wearing, so it could be pajamas, a school uniform, casual clothes, or whatever crazy outfit Tomoyo designs for her.

I'm very curious about how this is done. The magic effects and shots of the key could be reused, but Sakura's motions look extremely similar each time despite the change in clothing. It's not a long sequence, but it still looks nice, and I can't imagine it was easy (or cheap) to continually produce new ones with different outfits.

How were these scenes made?

Comment: Is the way her hair move identical? If yes, I imagine them to use different layer for her clothes. If not, well it could just mean they simply redrawn the whole scene